# setInterval not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, match, address-bar

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).load(function(){
        $('#background_cycler').fadeIn(1500);//fade the background back in once all the images are loaded

      // run every 7s  
      if(typeof window.chrome != "object") {
                setInterval('cycleImages()', 60000);  
      } else {
                setInterval('cycleImages()', 60000);  
      }

      var urlvid = location.href.match(/vid/i);
      if (urlvid) {
                setInterval('cycleImages()', 70000000);  
      }
        var browserName=navigator.appName; if (browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") { setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000); }
```

This script should change the amount of time that background images switch for different browsers. I need this because Firefox and Chrome usually lag when changing images in background. IE does not do so.
This gets really worse, when watching videos so I'd like to check for /vid/ in the address bar and set the changing time to (almost) never. The thing is, it still changes every 60s on [this link](http://lightningsoul.com/media/vid/music/773/ARIANA-GRANDE-PROBLEM#content) in Chrome and Firefox.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: protip: pass the function reference `cycleImages` instead of `'cycleImages()'`

Comment: Store the reference of the old `setInterval`. When creating a new one, delete the old timer.

Comment: *Firefox and Chrome usually lag when changing images in background* - why don't you preload all the images in the background?

Comment: The problem isn't with the loading but with the Fade. They already are preloaded and fade in once loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You setup intervals twice. You need reorder your code or clear prevoius interval. Every call to `setInterval` create repeated timer, that calls your function.

```
var urlvid = location.href.match(/vid/i);
if (urlvid) {
  setInterval(cycleImages, 70000000);  
}else{
  // run every 7s  
  if(typeof window.chrome != "object") {
    setInterval(cycleImages, 60000);  
  } else {
    setInterval(cycleImages, 60000);  
  }
}
```

Better way to do this is define timeout as variable, change it according your browser rules, and then call `setInterval` with it.

```
var delay = 6000;
if(location.href.match(/vid/i)){
  delay = 70000000;
}
setInterval(cycleImages, delay);
```